# Outputting multiple reports in access vba causes error 3014, too many tables open

Tags: database, vba, reporting-services, runtime-error, ms-access-2010

I am working writing out reports from our company database using VBA and MS Access 2010.  I have almost 3000 employees and I need to write out 10 different reports for each employee and then combine those 10 reports into one pdf per employee.  These files are then saved in directories that are sorted by their duty station.

The code I have written works great and does the job intended to do EXCEPT after writing out 1024 reports I receive an error.  Err.Number 3014, Cannot open anymore tables.

According to what I could find on the internet this has to do with the Jet table references and is tricky to troubleshoot.  I have followed what advice I could find I believe I have properly closed out everything after use.  I thought maybe the problem arose in the merge pdf files routine but even if you comment that out it still fails at 1024 reports.

I would like this code to be able to process about 30,000 reports without failing.  Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated.

```
Public Function combined_report(EmployeeSelectionQuery As String)

Dim DefaultPdfDir As String     ' contains path to where pdf files will be written on local computer
Dim rst As Recordset            ' recordset object for set of selected plots from query:Employees_COMBINED
Dim n_employees As Integer      ' Number of employees selected by query:Employees_COMBINED
Dim current_employee_number As Variant     ' current employee number, used when writing combined reports
Dim current_duty_station As Variant     ' current duty station, used when writing combined reports
Dim strWhere As String          ' String containing the where clause for the combined openreport WhereCondition
Dim arrayReport(0 To 9) As Variant      ' Array containing all the reports to be processed in combined
Dim strReport As Variant        ' String containing prefix to reports
Dim tempOutputPdfFile As String ' Individual report before they are combined
Dim combinedOutputPdfFile As String     ' Combined report composed of individual reports REQUIRES that adobe acrobat - full version be installed.
Dim intCounter As Integer       ' A iteration counter used to update the status bar
Dim combOutputPdfFile As String ' Combined Output Pdf File Path

On Error GoTo error_handler

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(EmployeeSelectionQuery)

'Force Access to accurately update .RecordCount property
rst.MoveLast
rst.MoveFirst
n_employees = rst.RecordCount

If n_employees = 0 Then
  Call MsgBox("No employees selected by query: " & EmployeeSelectionQuery, vbCritical + vbOKOnly + vbDefaultButton1, "No Employees Selected")
  combined_report = False
Else

  DoCmd.Hourglass True

  'Set HomeDir and create output folder
  DefaultPdfDir = "C:\temp"
  MakeDir DefaultPdfDir


  arrayReport(0) = "REPORT_1"
  arrayReport(1) = "REPORT_2"
  arrayReport(2) = "REPORT_3"
  arrayReport(3) = "REPORT_4"
  arrayReport(4) = "REPORT_5"
  arrayReport(5) = "REPORT_6"
  arrayReport(6) = "REPORT_7"
  arrayReport(7) = "REPORT_8"
  arrayReport(8) = "REPORT_9"
  arrayReport(9) = "REPORT_10"


  'Set counter to zero
  intCounter = 0

  Do While (Not (rst.EOF))

        'Get employee number and duty station to name the files and sort by directory
        current_employee_number = rst!EN
        current_duty_station = rst!DUTY_STATION

        'Make the output directory if it doesn't exist and specify the output file path
        MakeDir "C:\Final\" & current_duty_station
        combOutputPdfFile = "C:Final\" & current_duty_station & "\" & current_employee_number & ".pdf"


        'Increment counter by one for each employee processed
        intCounter = intCounter + 1

        'Where statement used by DoCmd.OpenReport to run the report for one employee only
        strWhere = "[EN] = " & current_employee_number & " OR [en] = " & current_employee_number

        'Process each report
        For Each strReport In arrayReport

            'Specify the file path and name for the report
            tempOutputPdfFile = DefaultPdfDir & "\" & current_employee_number & "_" & strReport & ".pdf"

            'Update Status Bar
            Status ("Processing " & intCounter & " of " & n_employees & ": " & tempOutputPdfFile)

            'Open the report and write it to a pdf file
            DoCmd.OpenReport strReport, acViewPreview, "", strWhere, acHidden
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReport, acFormatPDF, tempOutputPdfFile, False
            DoCmd.Close acReport, strReport, acSaveNo

            'Merge the files
            MergePdfFiles combOutputPdfFile, tempOutputPdfFile, combOutputPdfFile


        Next strReport

        'Delete the last temp file before moving on to the next employee
        DeleteFile tempOutputPdfFile

    rst.MoveNext

  Loop

  'Close everything up
  Status ("")
  rst.Close
  Set rst = Nothing
  DoCmd.Hourglass False
  combined_report = True

End If

Exit Function
error_handler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & _
           "Description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "combined_report function error"
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    combined_report = False
    Status ("")

End Function
```

Comment: Hmmm.  Which line elicits the error?  I did a bit of reading on this, interesting issue.  I wonder if a paging-type solution would work.  Like only processing x amount of records at a time.  I wonder if the Jet table references would be tidied up if you jump out of the function...

Comment: I did try paging this by adding a stop and start parameter to the function.  Using macros I would run 1000 reports, step out of the function and then have a macro call the function for the next thousand reports.  I still got the same problem.  The Erl property points to the blank line between Status ("Processing.... and the comment  'Open the report and write it to a pdf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using DoCmd.OpenReport because it had the WHERE clause functionality built in. After reading JayRO-GreyBeard's comment I realized that it did seem redundant to use both the OpenReport and OutputTo methods. So, I rewrote the code, removing the OpenReport call and modified the QueryDef for each report prior to calling OutputTo.

For some reason this worked around the problem.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the "DoCmd.OutputTo" statement, see if it errors.  I am guessing this command is opening a report in addition to the report being opened in the prior DoCmd.OpenReport line.

(I would have just added this as a comment, but SO wouldn't let me)

Comment: Also, it's not the cause of your error, but typicall right after the "Loop" statement I would use a "rst.Close" statement.

Comment: I added the rst.Close line, thanks for catching that!

Comment: I also commented out the DoCmd.OutputTo statement and even after those two changes the code still quit after 1024 reports.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the 3014 Error.  I was outputting the report to PDF, while displaying the report on the screen for the user (using both Docmd.OpenReport and Docmd.OutputTo, which worked fine for single reports.  However, when I would batch run reports and export/display the reports. (The tool auto generates Purchase Orders)  The 3014 error would occur around 100 or so reports.

When I turned off the DoCmd.OpenReport for the batch run of reports to PDF.  The 3014 error went away.  I have retested, and can not run report batches in the 1000s with no problem.